# React download a pdf file from Node and open it in a tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I managed to get my upload to the server functionality work, however I am struggling with the download from the server.

I successfuly receive the file from the server, however I have no idea how to download it as a file or open it in a new tab (preferably).

So on the front end I have, a `Link` element with onClick that sends the request:

```
<Link
  onClick={(e) => {
    handleDownloadInvoice(e, invoice.scannedFileName);
  }}
  href={``}
>
```

and the handling function in react:

```
const handleDownloadInvoice = async (e, fileName) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const invoiceFile = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/invoice/getfile/${fileName}`, {
    headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },
  });

  console.log(invoiceFile);
};
```

From the server:

```
const getScannedFile = async (req, res) => {
  const { fileName } = req.params;

  res.contentType("application/pdf").sendFile(__basedir + `\\uploadedFiles\\invoices\\${fileName}`);
};
```

So the logged `invoiceFile` has the data as a string, and it has the correct `header: {content-type: "application/pdf" }`

The question is, how do I transform this data string back to a pdf file that either gets opened in a tab (preferably) or gets downloaded as a file to the clients computer?

Comment: @Sam I dont see how this is going to help me, I am at the point where I receive the file from the server as a string in `invoiceFile.data`, I don't know and can't find information how to proceed from there. Also files are stored in the nodejs server, not in the react app. Also I don't want to display it within the app, I want to open it in a new window and save the file to the computer of the client.

Comment: I use `jspdf` for such cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link , which can help

https://medium.com/@storrisi/how-to-show-a-pdf-stream-on-a-react-client-without-any-library-36220fee60cb

> ```js
> axios(`${apiURL}/pdf`, {
>    method: 'GET',
>    responseType: 'blob' //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
> })
> .then(response => {
> //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
>    const file = new Blob(
>      [response.data], 
>      {type: 'application/pdf'});
> //Build a URL from the file
>    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
> //Open the URL on new Window
>    window.open(fileURL);
> })
> .catch(error => {
>    console.log(error);
> });
> ```